# Magento get Layered Filter from Collection Programmatically

Tags: php, web-services, magento, layer, catalog

I am building custom webservices for the Mobile app,

I want to load filter according to product collection programmatically.

Currently i am getting filter on entire category but when we apply any filter it will gave same filter option again.

Below is the code which i have used for category filter

```
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer"); 
      $_category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id);
      $layer->setCurrentCategory($_category);
      $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();

      /* custom for filters
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
      $collection->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
      $collection->setAttributeSetFilter(array(4));
      $collection->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
      $collection->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
      $collection->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_filterable', array('gt' => 0));
      $attributes = $collection->load();
      */

      // print_r($attributes->getData());exit();
      $attributeCollection =array();

      $i=0;
      $attributeCollection = array();
      foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
         $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_price';
       }elseif($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal'){
         $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_decimal';
       }else{
        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
      }
      $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
      $attributeCollection[$i]['Code'] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
      $attributeCollection[$i]['Label'] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
      $j=0;
      $attributeOptionCollection =array();
      foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=='price'){
          $attributeOptionCollection[$j]['Label'] = strip_tags($option->getLabel());
        }else{
          $attributeOptionCollection[$j]['Label'] = $option->getLabel();
        }
        $attributeOptionCollection[$j]['Value'] = $option->getValue();
        $attributeOptionCollection[$j]['Type'] = $option->getFrontend();
        $j++;
      }
      $attributeCollection[$i]['Options'] = $attributeOptionCollection;
      $i++;
    }
    // print_r($attributeCollection);exit();
    // echo "<pre>";
    $counter = 0;
    $availableSortOptions = $_category->getavailablesortbyoptions();
    foreach ($availableSortOptions as $key=>$options) {
      $optinsList[$counter]['Code'] = $key;
      $optinsList[$counter]['Label'] =$options;
      $counter++;
      // print_r($options); 
    }
      $information['Filters'] = $attributeCollection;
```

Please suggest how i proceed

Comment: i will check and wil u result

Answer (score 2):

I used this for a particular Category - hope this helps

```
//require necessary files
require_once('../app/Mage.php');

$categoryID = $_POST['categoryID'];

//necessary initialization
Mage::app();
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

try{
    $json = array('status' => true);
    $json['data'] = array();
    $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
    $category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryID); // 3rd Category
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
    $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
        $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
        foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
            $count[] = array('attribute_name' => $option->getLabel(),'attribute_value' => $option->getValue());
        }
        if($count!=null){
            $json['data'][] = array('name'=>ucfirst($attribute->getAttributeCode()),'count'=>$count);
        }
        unset($count);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $json = array('status' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
echo json_encode($json);
```